# Unset variable causes fatal error?

Tags: php, unset

I have no idea why this is throwing an error - hoping someone can see the issue?

```
$client->set('place', 'home');
$client->placeInfo();
$client->screen($client->response());
$client->unset('place');
```

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined method
>   Client::unset()...

client class

```
// stores the client data
private $data = array();
// stores the result of the last method
private $response = NULL;

/**
* Sets data into the client data array. This will be later referenced by
* other methods in this object to extract data required.
*
* @param str $key - The data parameter
* @param str $value - The data value
* @return $this - The current (self) object
*/
public function set($key, $value) {
$this->data[$key] = $value;
return $this;
}

/**
* dels data in the client data array.
*
* @param str $key - The data parameter
* @return $this - The current (self) object
*/
public function del($key) {
unset($this->data[$key]);
return $this;
}

/**
* Gets data from the client data array.
*
* @param str $key - The data parameter
* @return str $value - The data value
*/
private function get($key) {
return $this->data[$key];
}

/**
* Returns the result / server response from the last method
*
* @return $this->response
*/
public function response() {
return $this->response;
}


public function placeInfo() {
$this->response = $this->srv()->placeInfo(array('place' => $this->get('place')));
return $this;
}
```

Comment: What is `unset()` declared to do?

Comment: $client = new Client($location, $wsdl, $username, $password);

Comment: @TomcatExodus It does not do anything, because it does not exist (according to the error message).

Comment: **@Oswald**: That's where I was going.

Comment: Updated question with remaining code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that there is no defined method `unset` on that class.  And you can't define one either because `unset` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).  You can't define a method with it as it's name.

```
public function unset($foo) // Fatal Error

public function _unset($foo) // Works fine
```

Rename the method to something else, and change the call...

**Edit:** Looking at the code you just edited in, you need to change the `$client->unset('place')` to `$client->del('place')`, since that's the method in the class definition...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Thank you. Updated question with remaining code, hopefully you can see the issue I'm having based on that. If your answer remains, I'm happy to go ahead and make the change.

Comment: Just a caveat on that **ircmaxell**; If logic is present in `__call()` for a method name of `if`, `unset`, etc., it will work, making it possible to achieve `$obj->unset($arg);`

Comment: @ircmaxell: Going by what you said, I should change it to: $client->del('place'); as the function for unsetting is "del"? :)

Comment: @Tomcat: I realized that, so I edited that part out of the answer.  It's still not possible to declare a function or method with that name.  But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for the lesson guys! Very much appreciated!! All fixed and working :)

Comment: `public function unset($foo)` yields a parse error (which is fatal, by nature). But you can fake it using `public function __call($name, $args) { if ($name == 'unset') echo "OK, I'm gone";  }`.

Comment: @ircmaxell: Yup, done before I noticed your comment. Just had to wait for the time to go down another minute before I could accept. Thank you again.